# Kingsman Taron Egerton swimming in the underwater scene

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

How far did Taron Egerton swim in the dorm scene in *Kingman: The Secret Service*? How long was the dorm and were safety divers used when making this scene?

Comment: There's multiple cuts/shots, so swimming time may not be as long as anticipated.  I'm assuming that safety divers would be an insurance requirement, or open the film up to charges of gross negligence.  Note that the camera and operators would also likely be underwater (as opposed to dry behind a glass partition).

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I couldn't follow was that at the very start  the dorm looked very long but as the scene progressed it seemed to me to be some what shorter perhaps it was the angles used that gave a sort of illusion. Just curious as to how long exactly the room was.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJaCjWldRyg) by Kingsman director [Matthew Vaughn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Vaughn) that answers at least some of your questions.

To summarize, the entire set was being lowered into a pool.  The process was controlled by a computer and meant to be done gradually, dropping several feet at a time and pausing to let the actors say their lines.  Unfortunately the computer malfunctioned and the set dropped 25 feet into the pool.  Vaughn says the fear on the actors' faces was real as they were essentially trapped.